# .exe file isnt opening (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an issue running the .exe file

The error is
[image: This]

(The game is a remake of [Find The invisible Cow](https://findtheinvisiblecow.com/))

I run this command in the windows terminal: `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py`

If i try running the command without `-w` flag the game's terminal opens when i execute the .exe file and closes.
This is the terminal error it gives me [error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv2JG.png) and [error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhvD.png)

Maybe the problem is that `pyinstaller` doesn't like `pygame` or some of the packages the code uses.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))

pygame.display.set_caption("Find The Cow")

# Cow
CowImg = pygame.image.load("Cow.png")
# Icon nd backround
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

backround = pygame.image.load("Backround.png")

# Text
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
# Score
font_score = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score_value = 0
# Def

def StartWinText():
    text = font.render('Press "Space" to play', True, (255,255,255))
    win.blit(text, (400,450))

def ScoreText(x,y):
    score_text = font_score.render('Score : ' + str(score_value), True, (255,255,255))
    win.blit(score_text, (x,y))
def CowImage(x,y):
    x -= 85
    y -= 73
    
    win.blit(CowImg, (x,y))

def XFinding(MouseX, CowX):
    Xoutput = MouseX - CowX
    if Xoutput < 20 and Xoutput > -20:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def YFinding(MouseY, CowY):
    Youtput = MouseY - CowY
    if Youtput < 20 and Youtput > -20:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def FoundCow(CowX,CowY):
    global game
    sound.set_volume(1)
    game = "start"
    CowImage(CowX, CowY)

def Volume(MouseX, MouseY):
    X = CowX
    Y = CowY
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(MouseX - X,2) + math.pow(MouseY - Y,2)))
    distance = distance / 1000
    sound.set_volume(distance)

        
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('moo.mp3')
channel = sound.play(-1)

CowX = 500
CowY = 250
run = True
sound.set_volume(0)
game = "start"
while run:
    win.blit(backround, (0,0))
    if game == "setup":
        CowX = random.randint(0,1000)
        CowY = random.randint(0,1000)
        game = "play"
    
    MouseX, MouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if game == "play":
        ScoreText(10,10)
        
        Volume(MouseX, MouseY)
        
        FoundX = XFinding(MouseX, CowX)
        if FoundX:
            FoundY = YFinding(MouseY, CowY)
            if FoundY:
                FoundCow(CowX, CowY)
                score_value += 1

    if game == "start":
        sound.set_volume(0)
        
        CowImage(CowX,CowY)
        StartWinText()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    game = "setup"

    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                sound.set_volume(0.1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                sound.set_volume(0.5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_3:
                sound.set_volume(1)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: what does the error shows?

Comment: Try that command without -w flag then post the error from the command line